# Factor group of all the sequences by the subgroup of bounded sequences

Tags: gr.group-theory, sequences-and-series, factorization, infinite-sequences

Consider the group G of the sequences of real numbers (the group operation is addition). It contains a subgroup H of bounded sequences.

Is there any nice description of the factor group G/H ?

It is rather uncomfortable to think about this factor group: there is nothing like canonical representative in each coset. Basically, I see no means of thinking about this group except the straightforward  definition of the factor group.

Comment: The isomorphism type of this group is all but mysterious: every torsion-free divisible abelian group of uncountable cardinal $\kappa$ is isomorphic to a $\mathbf{Q}$-vector space with basis of cardinal $\kappa$. In particular, the group you're mentioning is isomorphic to $\mathbf{R}$ itself (of course, in a highly non-canonical way).

Comment: There are many similar quotient groups: replace the group of bounded sequences by the group of sequences having at most polynomial growth (of degree at most $k$), at most intermediate growth, etc. Are some of these quotient groups isomorphic?